# Assign tasks to groups?

Tags: 2010, workflow

One of my users wants to make workflows for list item instances or documents, I know thats possible.  But for each step in the workflow a tasks needs to be created for somebody to review them and move to the next step.
The problem is that someone could be a group of people,  Can we do that?  Assign a task to a group?

What other approaches would you suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can assign task forms to a group. This is accomplished by using the action item "Collect data from a User" in SharePoint Designer.

When this option is selected, you can basically assign the review task for a single person or a SharePoint or AD group.

Please visit this article for the detailed explanation - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/collect-data-from-a-user-in-a-workflow-HA010209808.aspx